# Why didn't Adam divorce from Eve?

Tags: tanach

Following the sin of Eve, in which she tried to 'poison' Adam spiritually with the fruit and she misled him, Why didn't Adam divorce her? Moreover, he intimated with her and bore two children?

Comment: Well kayin and hevel were born before the sin according to the gemara.

Comment: Note that Shes was born after 130 years so that Adam and Chava stayed apart for that long until they reconciled. Adam did not *divorce* her because he considered himself guilty.  There was noone else so Adam could not have had other children by anyone else (Only the daughters of Cain would have existed in that time). Eve was also not guilty of adultery.

Comment: 1. It is not clear that they were married, to begin with
2. The Kabbalah does mention him distancing from her and sitting in the Gihon river for 130 years.
3. He was commanded on being fruitful and filling the land, I think that should override the desire for divorce
4. As he couldn't marry anyone else, there was no difference between divorcing or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere is it stated that one must (or should) divorce if their wife causes them to transgress a sin. Judaism views divorce as a last resort when reconciliation is impossible. It isn't surprising that the first man ever created was able to find a way to reconciliate without needing to divorce.